# Getting the values of textboxes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, textbox

I have this html code:

```
<table border="" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" id="mytable">

<tbody><tr><td>Song:</td> <td><input type="text" name="song" maxlength="64" size="48" /> </td></tr>
<tr><td>Artist:</td> <td><input type="text" name="artist" maxlength="16" size="48" /> </td></tr>
```

How do I get the values of "song" and "artist"? I have tried:

```
var elTableCells = mytable.getElementsByTagName("td");
alert(elTableCells[2].value);
alert(elTableCells[4].value);
```

but I keep getting "undefined" even when there is text inside the textbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `td` elements don't have a `value` attribute, so calling `.value` on them won't do a thing.  Second, the value is actually on the `input` element, so you need to do `mytable.getElementsByTagName('input')` instead.  Even better would be to give your input fields ids and then use `getElementById`.  This would mean you could alter your HTML without your JS breaking.

Answer (score 1):

Download [jquery](http://jquery.com/)

```
jQuery("input[name='song']").val()
```

To try and resolve the argument below. This can be down with plain javascript as above but for simplicity and cross browser standardisation I would recommend jQuery. It is a widely used and generally highly recommended library.

Comment: jQuery is not the answer to every Javascript question.

Comment: The simpler alternative `$("input[name='song']").val()`

Comment: ... especially when the OP is already using plain JavaScript.

Comment: 'the answer' . . . no, but when it comes to the DOM jquery is 'an answer', even 'a correct answer'. There's more than one right answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var song   = document.getElementsByName("song").value;
var artist = document.getElementsByName("artist").value;
```

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns a DOMNodeList. You need to use `document.getElementsByName("song")[0].value`.

Comment: Note that this method behaves very differently in [FF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName) and [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536438(v=vs.85).aspx). In IE, also elements with a matching ID will be returned, but no elements that have a `name` attribute but officially not support it. Whereas in FF, only elements with matching `name` s are returned whether they officially support it or not. See also: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t125

Answer (score 1):

The tagName that is relevant here is "input", not td. That will get you what you're looking for.

It's almost a cliche on StackOverflow, but I suggest you take a look at JQuery. JQuery allows you to treat your html as a database and query it to get this kind of stuff. If your markup was like this:

```
<input type="text" id="song" maxlength="64" size="48" />
```

You could get the value like this:

```
$("#id").value();
```

If you wanted to get the value of the maxlength attribute on it, you could do this:

```
$("#id").attr("maxlength");
```

Much more fun than digging through element arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(document.getElementsByName("song")[0].value);
alert(document.getElementsByName("artist")[0].value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this to work effectively, Below I am getting a date from an asp.net textbox and then getting today's date. I then send both dates through a function to get the number of months that I need to do my calculation (be aware that the code uses Infragistics libraries (if you intent to copy and paste, replace those calls with standard JavaScript calls):

```
function calculateMonthlyRepayment() 

    var tStartDate = $find('dp_Start_Date');
    var startDate = tStartDate.get_value();
    var today = new Date();
    var numMonths = monthDiff(startDate, today);     
    var rate = igedit_getById('WebNumericEdit_InterestRate').getValue() * 0.01;
    var intRate = (rate / 100) / 12;
    var principal = igedit_getById('WebCurrencyEdit_Proposed_Owing').getValue();
    var repayment = (principal * (Math.pow((1 + intRate), numMonths)) * intRate / (Math.pow((1 + intRate), numMonths) - 1));

    igedit_getById('txt_Monthly_Repayment').setValue(repayment);

}
function monthDiff(d1, d2) {
    var months;
    months = (d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()) * 12;
    months -= d1.getMonth() + 1;
    months += d2.getMonth();
    return months <= 0 ? 0 : months;
}
```